# Get pattern from rising numbers

Tags: function-construction, series-expansion

I am no mathematician or math star, yet wondering if there is a formula or a way to calculate what follows:

I have series of numbers:

```
1, 4.8, 10.56, 20.08, 125.9, 500.76
```

How to calculate n-th number in sequence knowing only starting ones?

Also what, if series goes like this - where sequence is not only rising, but falls down in certain places (call it unregular sequence):

```
1, 4.8, 10.56, 20.08, 2.64 125.9, 500.76
```

I am planning to make RPG game and trying to figure out difficulty rising bar.

Comment: The people who voted to close wont be notified of your comment. Anyway I don't think that other question solves this. With the information given there are an infinite number of ways to continue the sequences. You could play around with `FindFit` and see if you can find a simple model that matches the pattern more or less